# Remove the current product in vue and vuex and js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

*Hell0 I want to remove the current which cursor had pointed product from the carts but actually, splice method does remove on the top product from carts ..here I need help to remove the current product from the carts*

```
     // actions 
     removeProductFromCart({commit}){
          commit('REMOVE_PRODUCT_FROM_CART')
          console.log('commit')

       },
     // mutations 
     REMOVE_PRODUCT_FROM_CART (state, id){

        const index = state.carts
        index.findIndex(product => product.id == id)
        state.carts = index
        state.carts.splice(index, 1)
        }, 
      

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <template>
      <div class="cart-info">
        <img :src="getImageURL()" />
        <div class="product-info-right-bar">
          <div class="cart-det">
            <h2>{{ product.product_name }}</h2>
            <span
              >{{ product.product_sale_price }} x {{     product.qty }} = Rs:{{ total }}
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="right-menu">
            <inc-dec :product="product"></inc-dec>
            <fa-icon
              @click.prevent="removeCart()"
              class="dele"
              :icon="['fas', 'trash-alt']"
            ></fa-icon>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>
 methods:{
    ...mapActions(["increaseProduct","decreaseProduct","removeProductFromCart" ]),
    removeCart(){
      this.removeProductFromCart()
    },
on click i call removeProduct() function above 
 methods:{
    ...mapActions(["increaseProduct","decreaseProduct","removeProductFromCart" ]),
    removeCart(){
      this.removeProductFromCart()
    },
```

Comment: you are not passing `id` to `removeCart()` method

Comment: when I passing id it's not working because on addCartPrduct I had sent all product even increment and decrement too

Comment: you need to pass `id` to `removeCart`

Comment: Thankyou it's now workingg actually i'm not able to pass id

Comment: awesome. glad i could help you